# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b61d10

Tags: iphone, ios, error-handling

I am practicing delegate in iphone development but have a problem

2012-05-12 21:21:54.279 DelegatePractice[2924:f803] -[secondViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b61d10
2012-05-12 21:21:54.281 DelegatePractice[2924:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[secondViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b61d10'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13bb052 0x154cd0a 0x13bcced 0x1321f00 0x1321ce2 0x2596 0x436e1e 0x13bcec9 0x155c2 0x250d54 0x13bcec9 0x155c2 0x1555a 0xbab76 0xbb03f 0xba2fe 0x3aa30 0x3ac56 0x21384 0x14aa9 0x12a5fa9 0x138f1c5 0x12f4022 0x12f290a 0x12f1db4 0x12f1ccb 0x12a4879 0x12a493e 0x12a9b 0x1e98 0x1df5)

and I think I set up the delegate properly:

delegateViewController.m

```
- (void)secondViewControllerDidJump:
(secondViewController *)controller
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"jump"])
    {
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        secondViewController *SecondViewController =[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
        SecondViewController.delegate = self;
    }
}

@end
```

secondViewController.h

```
@class secondViewController;

@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)secondViewControllerDidJump: (secondViewController *)controller;

@end

@interface secondViewController : UITableViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *choices;
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)jump:(id)sender;

@end
```

secondViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)jump:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate secondViewControllerDidJump:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app crashes in these lines:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
secondViewController *SecondViewController =[[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
```

You ask `navigationController` for its `viewControllers`, but the log makes clear that `navigationController` is **not** a `UINavigationController` but a `secondViewController`, which does not respond to the selector `-viewControllers`.

Make sure that `segue.destinationViewController` really returns a `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Can you show me the correct code? coz as far as I see it, navigationController is a UINavigationController, I really don't understand

Comment: Did you try logging its class like `NSLog(@"%@", [navigationController class])`? I cannot give you the proper code since I never did and never will work with storyboards.

Comment: I logged it and it's 2012-05-12 21:53:12.157 DelegatePractice[3250:f803] secondViewController,thst's strange,how?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, i solved by using:

```
secondViewController *SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
```

Basically segue.destinationViewController returns a view controller, so use it.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
secondViewController *SecondViewController =[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
```