# Error when performing segue: -[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield, uistoryboardsegue

I have some code to change to another screen in my app:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    NSString *dataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Performing Segue...");
    // Open detail segue
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewSegue" sender:dataString];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)json
{
    NSLog(@"Testing...");
    // If we are going to the success view, send the JSON data over as well!
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"DetailViewSegue"]) {
        DetailViewController *DetailViewControllerSegue = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSDictionary *jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue = (NSDictionary*)json;
        DetailViewControllerSegue.jsonString = jsonSendetAsParamInPerformSegue;

    }
}
```

When I attempt to perform the segue I get this error: `-[UITextField length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14589970`

What does error mean? And how can I resolve it?

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Are there any text fields being accessed/manipulated in the next view's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear?

Comment: (Also what is "dataString" supposed to be?)

Comment: dataString is a JSON string received from a web server. I can confirm the dataString is fine as I call it in an NSLog. Some text fields are being manipulated in the viewDidLoad, I will check that out now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b61d10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564175/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-0x6b61d10)

Comment: SO has millions of questions. Why can't people stop closing them due to duplicate questions, it's expected!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this error appeared was because I had a typo in my Storyboard Segue Identifier and it didn't match:

```
@"DetailViewSegue"
```

in:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"DetailViewSegue" sender:dataString];
```

I hope this helps others in the future

Peter

Comment: if that's the case please accept your own answer to close this question.

Comment: @Marco you need to wait at least 2 days before you can accept your own answer. Stupid, I know.

Comment: I did not know that. In any case thank you for posting an answer to your own question, not everyone takes the time to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`UITextField` doesn't have a selector called `length`.  What you probably want is to call `length` on the `text` property of the text field.

```
[someTextField.text length]
```

(I actually don't see anything related to a text field in the posted code... but this is the only explanation per the given error message)

Comment: I don't understand why though? And I have a few text fields in the viewcontroller. Also, none of the text fields have anything to do segue being changed?

Comment: Just look through your code and figure out where you're calling the `length` selector.  That's clearly where the problem is.  I don't understand why either, as you've posted no code that relates to the error message you're getting.

Comment: I'm am not calling the length selector at all though. This is where I am confused?

Comment: @PeterStuart - Look at the exception stack!!